# jQuery load a page on click then automatically load a div

Tags: jquery

I am wanting to redirect a page on click, and then load specified content into on of those pages div.

How do I go about doing this?

For example:

```
<div id="redirect">Click here to go to new page</div>
```

When the new page loads, there will be a div with `id = content` that needs to have content automatically loaded via ajax based on data sent from the redirect id on the previous page.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
$(function(){
 $('#redirect').click(function(){
   window.location = 'your_page.php?id=' + id_here;
 });
});
```

On the next page you can load data anyway you want based on the `id` query string value.

Answer (score 1):

How about good old HTML?

```
<div><a href="page.ext?id=1">Click here to go to new page</a></div>
```

Then, use some server-side technology to render the desired content on page.ext.

Comment: The problem is that I'm working with an already developed system, and the way it works is through loading divs with ajax calls.